# How can I shorten an array in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust

How can I efficiently implement:

```
fn shorten(arg: [u8; 32]) -> [u8; 30] {
    ???
}
```

which throws away the last two bytes?

Obviously I could use a for loop, and create a new shorter array on the stack.

There *appears* to be an opportunity for the compiler to leave `[u8; 32]` on the stack and just use the `[u8; 30]` of it.

Generally I would use slices, but here I need to return a shorter array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of those questions where the straight answer isn't really worth much. But let's start with the straight answer: You can implement the function as

```rust
fn shorten(arg: [u8; 32]) -> [u8; 30] {
    std::array::from_fn(|i| arg[i])
}
// or
fn shorten(arg: [u8; 32]) -> [u8; 30] {
    arg[..30].try_into().unwrap()
}
// or
fn shorten(arg: [u8; 32]) -> [u8; 30] {
    let mut ret = [0; 30];
    ret.copy_from_slice(&arg[..30]);
    ret
}
// or
fn shorten(arg: [u8; 32]) -> [u8; 30] {
    let mut ret = [0; 30];
    for i in 0..30 {
        ret[i] = arg[i];
    }
    ret
}
```

Ignoring the scaffolding for a function call, these all optimize down to four x86 instructions.

```
movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi]
movups  xmm1, xmmword ptr [rsi + 14]
movups  xmmword ptr [rdi + 14], xmm1
movups  xmmword ptr [rdi], xmm0
```

(See the trickery there, with overlapping load/store? Clever. -.-) [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:3,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:3,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:3),source:%27pub+fn+shorten(arg:+%5Bu8%3B+32%5D)+-%3E+%5Bu8%3B+30%5D+%7B%0A++++std::array::from_fn(%7Ci%7C+arg%5Bi%5D)%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:39.81981981981982,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:r1730,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-O%27,overrides:!((name:edition,value:%272021%27)),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+rustc+1.73.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.72932472932472,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27rustc+1.70.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+rustc+1.73.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:15.450855450855446,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Now, for the not-straight part of the answer: The problem is that it makes no sense to look at `fn shorten` in isolation:

- As long as `shorten` is its own function and returns an owned `[u8; 30]`, it must make a copy, as the return value is a separate value from the argument. It can't return a pointer to the argument, because the signature promises it returns a value.
- `shorten` is short and LLVM will most certainly inline it. And then the question is whether LLVM can figure out that whatever uses the result of `shorten` would also have been happy with the `[u8; 32]`. Whether it can do that or not isn't answerable with the information you provided.

Lastly, `shorten` is four x86 instructions. Are you really at a point where this is eating a significant part of your execution time?